# How to reverse proxy a TFS server

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

We're using a TFS server 2017 update 2 in our local office.
But we need access the server at home, we tried to use nginx for build a reverse proxy to access TFS server, but failed.
Also the Apache haven't ability to do that to pass the NTLM authorization of TFS.
Do someone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both nginx and Apache server can't handle NTLM authentication properly. Even if use "stream" server in nginx, it still throw exceptions at times. So the best way that I've found is to write a pure reverse proxy with socket in NodeJS.

Please try the code here: https://gist.github.com/gekowa/7fdd6fa6db51a7671de5469b3943a9da

The implementation was pretty straightforward, it just double pipe local and remote sockets, and everything is just fine.

Comment: how to make sure the program run in background?

Comment: pm2 would be a good choice. E.g., `pm2 start tcpproxy.js --name="TFS Proxy"  -- 8080 your_internal_server_address your_internal_port`

Answer (score 0):

node tcpproxy.js 8080 your_internal_server_address your_internal_port

Best choice：your_internal_port=8080