# NTLM issues with nginx using Team Foundation Server

Tags: nginx, tfs, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have configured a simple NGINX reverse proxy to use with TFS client for code check-in and checkouts and create build piplelines using Azure DevOps. The nginx proxy is configured on a cloud VM and TFS is located in om-prem data center so the requests comes to tfs via VPN tunnel. But we are getting multiple errors like:

Technical information (for administrator):
  HTTP code 413: Request Entity Too Large
D:\TFS\abc\Demo Project 9\Source Code\AES\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.2.8.1\content\ApplicationInsights.config.transform: TF30063: You are not authorized to access nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu).

Here is my proxy:

```
server {
   listen 8080;

   location /  {
      proxy_pass http://10.x.x.0:8080/tfs
   }
}
```

Comment: I have tried everything but nothing worked so we have revert back to the transparent connection. thanks anyway will keep on searching for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Nginx can't handle NTLM authentication properly.

As a workaround, you could try to write a pure reverse proxy with socket in NodeJS.

More detail about this, take a look at here: [How to reverse proxy a TFS server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45857746/how-to-reverse-proxy-a-tfs-server)